# Visual Studio 2008 Report Designer row visibility

Tags: visual-studio-2008, row, visibility, report-designer

Is it possible to write a VB code to determine the visibility of a footer of a group in a report in VS 2008? I have done that in VS 2010

[image]

but am not able to find such an option in VS 2008 and I am not able to use VS 2010. Is there a way to get that good dialog so I can write the code?

[image]

The closest thing to this seems row properties but it only has:

[image]

So, is there a solution to not show certain footers based on their group's values in VS2008 like it was in VS2010?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually this was pretty easy. I just looked up the code of 2010 version and added the same to 2008 (in xml version of the .rdlc) and it worked.

```
<TableRow>
    <Visibility>
        <Hidden>=IIF(some_condition, TRUE, FALSE)</Hidden>
    </Visibility>
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Also you could select "expression" in the properies-> visible->hidden->dropdown and add the same IIF() code there. That way you do not need to change the RDL file manually :)